# Gmap3 issue with style and hover

Tags: jquery, jquery-gmap3

I have questions about gmap3 integrate to my site.
This is my code
?

```
    $("#mapa").gmap3({


map:{
    options:{
      center:[41.993752,21.427277],
      zoom: 16,
      zoomControl: false,
      scaleControl: false,
      scrollwheel: false,
      disableDoubleClickZoom: false 
    }
  },
  marker:{
    values:[
      {latLng:[41.993889, 21.416522], options:{icon: "css/img/marker.png"}},
      {latLng:[41.99452, 21.433433], options:{icon: "css/img/marker.png"}}
    ],
    options:{
      draggable: false
    }

  }
});
```

1. The code above work if script in index file, but if i try to put from custom.js no work (no show map) why?
2. How to make gray map style to code above?
3. How to make hover effect to marker?

Thank you,
I hope undestand all what i need.

Comment: Is your custom js file being called after the plugin in script load?

Comment: yes is called, In custom.js i have more function, all work without gmap3